# What is the best way to image MacBook Pro hard drive?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I am thinking about upgrading my mid-2012 MacBook Pro by replacing its HD with an SSD. However, I have four partitions (2-3 for Mac OS X, the rest for windows). So, I was wondering: what is the best way to image/"clone" my HD to include all partitions so that when I transfer that image to the SSD all partitions will remain intact?

Comment: Try using Clonezilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dd` command from the Root terminal. To do so, you'll either need a Network Access Storage device that you can access, or the other hard drive hooked up *at the same time*.

If you have both hard drives, you'll need to figure out the names of the hard drives. In the Terminal (Applications->Utilities->Terminal), type `ls /dev` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll see some devices, including `disk0s1` for example. Look for the `diskx` entries, as you'll need to find the one with all the partitions, and one without ANY partitions. We'll call these `old` and `new`. Type the next command and press Enter, replacing the `x` with the number for the old and the number for the new: `sudo dd if=/dev/diskx of=/dev/disky`. The `x` should be the old disk (input), and the `y` should be the new disk (output). Be very careful of this though, as it will **WIPE ANY DATA ON THE NEW HARD DRIVE**.

If you just have one hard drive at a time, but have a NAS, you can change the above command with the `of=` switch to point to an image file that you create, for example `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0 of=/Volumes/NASDriveMountPoint/diskimage.img`. Make sure you know where your NAS device is mounted on your Mac. Once this is done, power down your Mac and put in the new hard drive. When you boot up from your Mac OSX DVD, choose the language and click Next. Then, select Tools->Terminal from the menu bar. I don't have the exact commands right now for mounting Network Storage devices, but once you have access, you'll type `sudo dd if=/Volumes/NASMountPoint/nameofimage.img of=/dev/disk0` and press Enter. Again **BE CAREFUL OF THIS COMMAND AS YOU WILL WIPE ALL THE INFORMATION OF `/dev/disk0`!**

Comment: Sounds like just what I need. Thanks! +1